# python move files on remote host

Tags: python, ssh, rsync, popen

I have a python script that needs to move a directory on a remote host from one location to another.

From a terminal, I can `ssh` into the remote host and then `mv -r src dest` will mv the relevant directory on that remote host.

```
> ssh USER@REMOTE
> mv -r SRC DEST
```

How can I do this through python?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

```
import paramiko
ssh = paramiko.SSHClient()
ssh.connect('REMOTE', username='USER', 
    password='PASSWORD')
stdin, stdout, stderr = \
ssh.exec_command("mv -r SRC DEST")
```